# What did the Dark Queen give to Rumplestiltskin for the Dark Curse?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

Of course in Once Upon a Time, things don't come cheaply for something off **Rumplestiltskin** and he usually wants things that are precious to you or outright silly to the person, but in time is much more bigger to his own agenda's and plans.

But what did the Dark Queen Regina offer to **Rumplestiltskin** in return for the **Dark Curse** that eventually ripped everyone from the enchanted forest and most off the other magical lands.

I have watched Seasons 1, 2 & 3 and I am not sure if I am missing something but if the answer is in one of the episodes, please include in your answer.

Comment: Do you mean the 'price' she paid? If so, I think it was Leopald no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

His freedom, power and wealth.

When Regina (the Evil Queen) came to Rumplestiltskin to make the deal for the Curse he was imprisoned by Prince Charming and Snow White, and was unable to free himself. His condition for helping her was that in the new world they'd be transported to he would be somebody with influence and power, wealthy and that the Evil Queen would give him anything he asked for, provided he said "please".

That no doubt seemed inconsequential to her. After all, she'd still have more power and wealth, and he's not supposed to remember anything about his previous life in the Enchanted Forest anyway. However, later in the episode - I don't remember exactly which one, but I'm sure it's in season one - it's made clear both to Regina and the viewers that Mr Gold (Rumplestiltskin) does, in fact, remember who he is and the details of the deal they made.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but I only just realised it while writing the answer and it's vaguely interesting: The Evil Queen's name is Regina, which also happens to be Latin for Queen (though pronounced differently). Not sure why I didn't make the connection earlier.

Comment: This isn't right at all.  The wealth and the "please" promise weren't in exchange for the Dark Curse - Regina already had the Dark Curse, and she tried to enact it with the heart of her horse but it didn't work.  So she made the wealth and please promise in exchange for Rumplestiltskin telling her what she was missing - he told her she needed to use the heart of the thing she loved most, which was her father.

Comment: And Rumplestiltskin didn't regain his memories until he heard the name "Emma" in the first episode.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Mr. Gold was the one who found Henry for Regina.  He had his memories the whole time.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist To Regina, [1x12, Skin Deep](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEhADNei8rs), but I think viewers knew before that

Comment: @Izkata Yes, Mr. Gold did get Henry for Regina, but he got him unintentionally.  He didn't know it was Emma's son, or even who Emma was.  The creators have confirmed that he only got his memories at the end of the first episode, when he hears the name "Emma" at Granny's inn.  The reason he regained his memories is that he had written "Emma" in squid ink in his jail cell, so that he'd be awoken once the savior arrived.

Comment: @Izkata The creators discuss this at the 6:30 mark of this interview: http://youtu.be/aoEay4JK9pI

Answer (score 3):

Rumple has been known to "give" things if he knows there's something in it for him. He knew his son was in our world. He knew he would not be the one to cast the Dark Curse. So he gave the Curse to Regina to reach this world to find Baelfire. Remember the flashback to his cell in season 3.

Rumple: "You've already promised me a good life in this new land. What more could I want from you?"

Regina: "To be let out of this cage...to be let out of our last deal. To escape the Curse."

Rumple: "But why would I desire that, dearie? I'm exactly where I want to be."

Comment: Yes, Rumple's real reason for wanting the curse cast was to get Baelfire.  But I assume that he nevertheless got something from Regina in exchange for the curse.  That's what Rumple often does: he exchanges A for B, but what he's really after is C.

Comment: Remember in season 2, Emma even accuses him of engineering her as the savior for his own benefit. I think Keshav is on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

The point is, the Evil Queen didn’t get the curse from Rumple, she got it from Maleficent!

Comment: Welcome to the community, @Parva. Unfortunately, this question already has a comprehensive answer that's been accepted. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to post things like this as a comment on the existing post.